# Shiny Dashboard tabBox, tabPanel CSS

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

When using tabBox and tabPanel in Shiny dashboard,

```
fluidRow(
    tabBox(
      title = "First tabBox",
      # The id lets us use input$tabset1 on the server to find the current tab
      id = "tabset1", height = "250px",
      tabPanel("Tab1", "First tab content"),
      tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2")
    ),
```

is it possible to modify background color and other CSS settings? I have tried

```
.tab-pane
```

but this changes the background color of the entire dashboard, not only the panel.

Answer (score 0):

```
fluidRow(
    tags$style(".nav-tabs {background: #f4f4f4;}
                .nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs li.active:hover a, .nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs li.active a {background-color: #fff;
                                               border-color: #fff;                                                      
                                               }
                .nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs li.active {border-top-color: 
                                                      #314a6d;
                                                      }"
                ),
    tabBox(
      title = "First tabBox",
      id = "tabset1", height = "250px",
      tabPanel("Tab1", "First tab content"),
      tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2")
      )
```

Comment: You can try this, the colour of the select panel will be white, and the colour of the rest panels will be light grey.